# Cron reinstallation

Tags: cron

Can cron be reinstalled? If so, how to take cron job backups created by system and applications like postfix, apache etc.,

Now after taking backups how to reinstall cron?

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can reinstall cron with :

```
      sudo apt-get --reinstall install paquete
```

reinstall dont delete your conf files, but if you want a backup, you nedd the next files and folder for cron's system :

```
   /etc/crontab

   /etc/cron.d/
   /etc/cron.daily/
   /etc/cron.hourly
   /etc/cron.monthly
   /etc/cron.weekly
```

and for user's cron :

```
    /var/spool/cron/
```

Comment: You have searched for packages that names contain paquete in all suites, all sections, and all architectures.

Sorry, your search gave no results. did you mean to say cron perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

On debian you simply need to use:

```
 sudo systemctl unmask cron.service && sudo apt --reinstall install cron
```

Comment: You might want to check if the service is masked before bothering to unmask it...  sudo systemctl status cron.service